# gcloud datastore emulator crashes when creating indexes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, emulation, gcloud, datastore

my project uses Dialogflow connected to Google datastore via cloud functions, and I'm trying to use gcloud datastore emulator to update my index configuration file with some composite indexes. I am new to using gcloud sdk and can't figure out why the emulator crashes when I use the indexes create command.

Using the advice in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator?authuser=2#starting_the_emulator), I can start the emulator successfully with `gcloud beta emulators datastore start` and then automatically set environment variables in a separate terminal window with `$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)`. However, when I use the command `gcloud datastore indexes create ~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/index.yaml` (docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools?authuser=2#the_development_workflow_using_gcloud)), I see the following error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I have ensured that gcloud is up to date and there are no errors discoverable through `gcloud info --run-diagnostic`, so I think it must be a user error, but the documentation has not been very helpful in discovering where I've gone wrong.

Another (related?) issue is that after I start the emulator and then use my application on my local machine, I don't see any changes in the terminal which leads me to believe that the emulator is not properly connected to my application, and therefore no further indexes have been created by my use of datastore emulator.

Thank you, I appreciate any advice or pointing to useful resources.

Full trace:

```
Trace:
command_lib/crash_handling.py:190
 target_function(*args, **kwargs)
gcloud_main.py:174
 gcloud_cli.Execute()
calliope/cli.py:1008
 self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)
calliope/cli.py:1045
 exceptions.HandleError(exc, command_path_string, self.__known_error_handler)
calliope/exceptions.py:551
 core_exceptions.reraise(exc)
core/exceptions.py:146
 six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
six/__init__.py:693
 raise value
calliope/cli.py:982
 resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
calliope/backend.py:809
 resources = command_instance.Run(args)
surface/datastore/indexes/create.py:77
 index_api.CreateMissingIndexes(project, info.parsed)
api_lib/datastore/index_api.py:160
 normalized_indexes = NormalizeIndexes(index_definitions.indexes)
api_lib/datastore/index_api.py:106
 for index in indexes:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Confirm that you are running the index create command in the same terminal as the `$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)`.

Comment: Include your index.yam file stored in `~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/index.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for your input @Juancki! Yes I've done both of those things but unfortunately the error persists

Comment: Include the file in the question I mean